# Comparing fits in simulation for power analysis

Tags: r, simulation, statistical-power

I have the following data (just an small example here). I want to know effect of time and ecotype over height. 
`subdata <-
id time ecotype height
1   17   a  73.692
1   22   a  213.010
1   25   a  343.700
1   28   a  663.030
109 32   a 1267.300
109 17   b   47.445
109 22   b  148.050
109 25   b  280.570
109 28   b  509.000
109 32   b  954.050
121 17   c   33.972
121 22   c   71.235
121 25   c  130.650
121 28   c  220.190
121 32   c  452.740
133 17   d   38.365
133 22   d   84.068
133 25   d  137.560
133 28   d  255.390
133 32   d  426.970`

I have fitted the following model

`m1 <- lme(height ~ ecotype*time + (time | id))`

and now I want to know the Power of this analysis
in order to do that I use simulation

`time <- (subdata$time)
ecotype <- as.factor(subdata$ecotype)
id <- subdata$id
height=subdata$height`

`m2 <- lmer(height ~ ecotype * time + (time| id), subdata)
s2 <- simulate(m2)
beta.hat=fixef(m2)
se=sqrt(diag(vcov(m2)))`

`k <- c()
B=1000
tstar=rep(0,B)
set.seed(781)
for(b in 1:B)
{
  ystar=drop(simulate(m2))
 ostar=lmer(ystar$sim_1~ecotype +(time|id))
  for(i in 2:19) {  k <- append(k, ((fixef(ostar)[i]-beta.hat[i])/sqrt(vcov(ostar)`[i,i]))) }}`

The problem I have is I don't know how to calculate an overall p-value to say this model's power is low or high. Normally, the examples on the web always have variables (e.g ecotype) with two classes so the results of the simulation will always produce one value. However, in my case I have n number of ecotypes therefore more than one output:

`fixef(ostar)
  (Intercept)  ecotypea  ecotypeb   ecotypec ecotyped
     78.98846     -22.39385     -37.27676     -38.66168`

All I can think is to extract all the fixed effects estimates and the cv and compare them against, get a mean and compare it against a threshold (e.g. 0.05). However, I don’t know whether that’s right. Please can you give me a hand on this
Please can you suggest how can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my question by doing the following:

`library(lmerTest)`

`simulateFixedEffect <- function(model,ecotype, time, id, B)
{
  Fvalue=rep(0,B);
  set.seed(781);
  for(b in 1:B)
  {
    s1=drop(simulate(model));
    ms=lmer(s1$sim_1 ~ ecotype*time + (time|id));
    Pvalue[b] <- anova(ms)[[6]][3];
  }
    return(Pvalue);

}`

`plotValue <- function(Fvalue, alpha = 0.05)
{ 
  mean(Fvalue>alpha);
  hist(Fvalue,30,prob=T,xlab="",ylab="",main="")
  x<-seq(0,15,0.1)
  lines(x,df(x,1,80),col="red")
  grid()
}`

`b <-  calculateT(m1);
Pvalue <- simulateFixedEffect(m1,ecotype, time, id, 10);
plotValue(Pvalue);`